# PHP leaves partial xml tags

Tags: php, xml

I have a PHP page on my site that is basically a simple receiver for reporting for my software.  If users have reporting turned on it submits some basic value pairs to my php page which then records them to an xml file on my server.  This seems to work very well, except that sometimes (fairly frequently) the xml files it creates have what looks to be a truncated extra piece of xml at the end of the file which makes it not valid xml.  It's easy to fix as I can just delete the truncated part and it's valid again but I'm not sure why it's doing that and if it's missing some data that should be there.

As an example, here is a simplified version of one recent file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<RDSoftwareReports>
  <RDSoftwareReport SoftwareType="workFlow">
    <ProgramTime Open="9:58:07 AM" Close="4:00:17 PM"/>
    <Commands/>
  </RDSoftwareReport>
</RDSoftwareReports>
reReport>
</RDSoftwareReports>
```

You can see that the last two lines look like they are the end of another file and report that got stuck in there.  This is accessed pretty regularly so I don't know if it's an issue with concurrency or multiple machines submitting reports at the same time or something else but if anyone has any insight I would be most grateful :).

Here is my php code:

```
<?php
$software = $_POST["swType"];
$rvtVersion = $_POST["rvtVer"];
$id = $_POST["id"];
$version = $_POST["ver"];
$path = $_POST["path"];
$licenseType = $_POST["lType"];
$licenseScope = $_POST["lScope"];
$osVersion = $_POST["osVer"];
$osNumerical = $_POST["osNum"];
$os64 = $_POST["os64"];
$specialVersion = $_POST["spVer"];
$programOpen = $_POST["pOpen"];
$programClose = $_POST["pClose"];
$fileData = $_POST["fData"];
$commandData = $_POST["cmds"];
$reportDate = date("m/d/Y");

//Get the report path, one per day
$reportPath = "Reports_".date("m_d_Y").".xml";

//echo $reportPath."<br /><br />";

//Create the file for today if it doesn't exist
if(!file_exists($reportPath))
{
    $writer = new XMLWriter();
    $writer->openUri($reportPath);
    $writer->startDocument('1.0','UTF-8');
    $writer->setIndent(4);
    $writer->startElement("RDSoftwareReports");
    $writer->endElement();  
    $writer->endDocument();
    $writer->flush();
}

//echo $reportPath."<br /><br />";

//Read the xml file in
$xml = simplexml_load_file($reportPath);
$reportNode = $xml->addChild("RDSoftwareReport");
$reportNode->addAttribute("SoftwareType",$software);
$reportNode->addAttribute("RevitVersion",$rvtVersion);
$reportNode->addAttribute("ID",$id);
$reportNode->addAttribute("ReportDate",$reportDate);
$reportNode->addAttribute("Version",$version);
$reportNode->addAttribute("Path",$path);
$reportNode->addAttribute("LicenseType",$licenseType);
$reportNode->addAttribute("LicenseScope",$licenseScope);
$reportNode->addAttribute("OSVersion",$osVersion);
$reportNode->addAttribute("NumVersion",$osNumerical);
$reportNode->addAttribute("Is64Bit",$os64);
$reportNode->addAttribute("SpecialVersion",$specialVersion);
    $progNode = $reportNode->addChild("ProgramTime");
    $progNode->addAttribute("Open",$programOpen);
    $progNode->addAttribute("Close",$programClose);

    if($software=="workFlow" || $software=="SelectionMaster")
    {
        $allCmdNode = $reportNode->addChild("Commands");
        if($commandData !="")
        {
            $commands = explode('~',$commandData);
            foreach($commands as $cmd)
            {
                $cmdData = explode('|',$cmd);
                $cmdNode = $allCmdNode->addChild("Command");
                $cmdNode->addAttribute("Type",$cmdData[0]);
                $cmdNode->addAttribute("StartTime",$cmdData[1]);
                $cmdNode->addAttribute("EndTime",$cmdData[2]);
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $allFileNode = $reportNode->addChild("Files");
        if($fileData !="")
        {
            $files = explode('~',$fileData);
            foreach($files as $file)
            {
                $fData = explode('|',$file);
                $fileNode = $allFileNode->addChild("File");
                $fileNode->addAttribute("Open",$fData[0]);
                $fileNode->addAttribute("Close",$fData[1]);;
            }
        }
    }

$dom = new DOMDocument('1.0');
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$dom->formatOutput = true;
$dom->loadXML($xml->asXML());
$dom->save($reportPath);
//$xml->asXML($reportPath);

?>
```

**UPDATE**

After comments by @ThW I cleaned up my php code to only use the DOM API.  In initial tests it did not create the issue but the other php page didn't in the test either... I've deployed this so I will let it work for a while and then report back on the results.  Here is the new code:

```
<?php
$software = $_POST["swType"];
$rvtVersion = $_POST["rvtVer"];
$id = $_POST["id"];
$version = $_POST["ver"];
$path = $_POST["path"];
$licenseType = $_POST["lType"];
$licenseScope = $_POST["lScope"];
$osVersion = $_POST["osVer"];
$osNumerical = $_POST["osNum"];
$os64 = $_POST["os64"];
$specialVersion = $_POST["spVer"];
$programOpen = $_POST["pOpen"];
$programClose = $_POST["pClose"];
$fileData = $_POST["fData"];
$commandData = $_POST["cmds"];
$reportDate = date("m/d/Y");

if($software == "")
{
    header('Location: http://www.revolutiondesign.biz');
    die();
}

//Get the report path, one per day
$reportPath = "Reports_".date("m_d_Y").".xml";

//Create a document
$xml = new DOMDocument("1.0", "UTF-8");
$xml->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$xml->formatOutput = true;

//Create the file for today if it doesn't exist
if(file_exists($reportPath))
{
    //Read the xml file in
    $xml->load($reportPath);
}
else
{
    //File doesn't exist, initialize it
    $root = $xml->createElement("RDSoftwareReports");
    $xml->appendChild($root);
}

//The last child should be the root element, start there.
$root = $xml->lastChild;

//Create a node for this report and populate with data
$reportNode = $xml->createElement("RDSoftwareReport");

addAttribute($xml, $reportNode, "SoftwareType",$software);
addAttribute($xml, $reportNode, "RevitVersion",$rvtVersion);
addAttribute($xml, $reportNode, "ID",$id);
addAttribute($xml, $reportNode, "ReportDate",$reportDate);
addAttribute($xml, $reportNode, "Version",$version);
addAttribute($xml, $reportNode, "Path",$path);
addAttribute($xml, $reportNode, "LicenseType",$licenseType);
addAttribute($xml, $reportNode, "LicenseScope",$licenseScope);
addAttribute($xml, $reportNode, "OSVersion",$osVersion);
addAttribute($xml, $reportNode, "NumVersion",$osNumerical);
addAttribute($xml, $reportNode, "Is64Bit",$os64);
addAttribute($xml, $reportNode, "SpecialVersion",$specialVersion);
    $progNode = $xml->createElement("ProgramTime");
    addAttribute($xml, $progNode, "Open",$programOpen);
    addAttribute($xml, $progNode, "Close",$programClose);
    $reportNode->appendChild($progNode);

    if($software=="workFlow" || $software=="SelectionMaster")
    {
        $allCmdNode = $xml->createElement("Commands");
        if($commandData !="")
        {
            $commands = explode('~',$commandData);
            foreach($commands as $cmd)
            {
                $cmdData = explode('|',$cmd);
                $cmdNode = $xml->createElement("Command");
                addAttribute($xml, $cmdNode, "Type",$cmdData[0]);
                addAttribute($xml, $cmdNode, "StartTime",$cmdData[1]);
                addAttribute($xml, $cmdNode, "EndTime",$cmdData[2]);
                $allCmdNode->appendChild($cmdNode);
            }
        }
        $reportNode->appendChild($allCmdNode);
    }
    else
    {
        $allFileNode = $xml->createElement("Files");
        if($fileData !="")
        {
            $files = explode('~',$fileData);
            foreach($files as $file)
            {
                $fData = explode('|',$file);
                $fileNode = $xml->createElement("File");
                addAttribute($xml, $fileNode, "Open",$fData[0]);
                addAttribute($xml, $fileNode, "Close",$fData[1]);;
                $allFileNode->appendChild($fileNode);
            }
        }
        $reportNode->appendChild($allFileNode);
    }
$root->appendChild($reportNode);

//Save to file
$xml->save($reportPath);

//Function to add an attribute with one line
function addAttribute($dom, $rootNode, $attName, $attValue)
{
    $att = $dom->createAttribute($attName);
    $attVal = $dom->createTextNode($attValue);
    $att->appendChild($attVal);
    $rootNode->appendChild($att);
}

?>
```

**UPDATE**
Ok well that didn't work... I deployed it and checked the reports shortly after and it was truncated at the end, only this time it didn't have the partial tags at the end, it was just truncated leaving the root element unclosed.  Any other ideas?

Perhaps I need to have it write each report to an individual file and then consolidate every so often?

Comment: Why are you using 3 different APIs for a single job?

Comment: What do you mean?  I'm new to PHP so I may well be missing something but this is what I pulled together from looking online at various sources including here...

Comment: You're creating the basic XML with XMLWriter, then you load it into SimpleXML and add elements, load it into DOM and save it again. Each of the 3 Apis could create the XML.

Comment: Ok I will look into that more then, thank you.  Like I said I'm new with PHP (this is my first item to write completely myself).  Do you have any suggestions on which would be better to use in this case?

Comment: I prefer DOM for smaller documents with complex structures and XMLWriter for large lists of records. I don't use SimpleXML at all.